# Facing Build Errors in an Android Studio Project while importing sub modules

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I cloned an Android repository and added its submodules using `git submodule update --init`, so two more folders showed up along with the main module "app". The **libnetcipher** is a module of **OnionKit** project which was imported after the I ran the update command.

[image]

Now I'm facing build errors while running build.gradle of Onionkit project  as shown below:
[image]

The local.properties file as you can see exist in the project and has correct SDK location mentioned.

Then I've tried running `settings.gradle` file, with following contents:

`include ':app'
include ':app:libs:OnionKit:libnetcipher'`

and received this error:

[image]

What might be causing this I couldn't deduce, I've never used an Andriod project importing such dependencies/sub-modules in the past.

More Information: Running **build.gradle** for **Project:Android** and **Module:app** executes successfully.

My thoughts : There are 2 projects open right now, which seems wrong and also the SDK path that was shown as misconfigured seems to be that of the **OnionKit** project.

Repository link : https://github.com/duckduckgo/Android